problem with jupyter pytorch kernel dying
i am trying to show one single CIFAR10 image in the notebook.
but as soon as i run plt.imshow(image), I get an error saying the karnel had died. But the same code runs fine on google colab.
matplotlib version ---3.9.2
python version--- 3.12.7
here is the cell that is throwing the error -------
    device = 'cpu'

    image, labels = train_dataset[54]  \\ an image from the dataset that i am trying to display
    image = image.permute(1,2,0) \\ corrected the ordering of the dimensions h,w,c
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show(block=True)

this is the error that I am getting.please help.
Kernel Restarting
The kernel for Downloads/CIFAR-ResNet2.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
